# How frequent can I use Facebook-Graph-API calls without getting banned?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am retrieving webpage facebook likes against URL using http://graph.facebook.com/?id=https://www.example.com

I want to know that is the limit for using these request e.g. "xxx" urls in "xx" seconds? etc. How much frequent requests can get me banned?

Help appreciated.

Comment: There is absolutely no good answer to this question.  Facebook refuses to provide that information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single rate for reqs/sec. This rate is based on a lot of factors, such as number of users, and will vary between different apps. That being said, your use case is very basic and shouldn't cause you to hit any rate limiting. If you are, you should re-think how often you need to fetch likes.